# setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord app crashes in ios5

Tags: ios, ios5

Please help to solve this issue. 
Check my below code.
I am trying to record audio..everything works fine above ios 5.0
but crashes on ios5 for below line of code.

```
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers error:&err];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method is available from iOS 6.

[See documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAudioSession/setCategory%3awithOptions%3aerror%3a)

"Available in iOS 6.0 and later."

You can use respondsToselector: check for preventing crash.